# Finding SMART status of SATA disks in HP SmartArray

Tags: debian, raid, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, sata

I'm trying to find SMART params of the disks in my array, it seems that simple way does not work:

```
% smartctl -d sat --all /dev/sg0 -H
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-8-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
root@wrzos ~ % smartctl -d sat -T permissive -T permissive --all /dev/sg0 -H 
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-8-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Tue Jan 29 15:32:21 2019 CET
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
                  Checking to be sure by trying SMART RETURN STATUS command.
SMART support is: Unknown - Try option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.




% smartctl -d scsi  --all /dev/sg0 -H
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-8-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HP
Product:              P410
Revision:             6.40
Serial number:        111111111111
Device type:          storage array
Local Time is:        Tue Jan 29 15:29:34 2019 CET
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
```

Is there any other way I can query status of those (SATA) disks?

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
smartctl -a -l ssd /dev/sda -d cciss,1
```

or

```
smartctl -a -l ssd /dev/sda -d sat+cciss,1
```

you can count the last number then up to select the new HDD.

this will result in:

```
root@pve:~# smartctl -a -l ssd /dev/sda -d cciss,1
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.44-2-pve] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 840 EVO 1TB
Serial Number:    S1D9NAADA00000W
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 85006hd19
Firmware Version: EXT0BB0Q
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Sep 21 13:38:26 2020 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (15000) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 250) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       40839
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       47
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   059   059   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       496
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   078   048   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       46
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       187862960327

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

Device Statistics (GP/SMART Log 0x04) not supported
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use smartctl with HP servers.

HP has purpose built tools for these, so the `ssacli` and `ssaducli` utilities would be the most helpful.

https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/

To get array status, something like `ssacli ctrl all show config detail` would provide that.

Comment: This will not show SMART values.